# getting a list of all objects of a class

Tags: java, class, inheritance, reflection

Is there a way to get a list of all Objects of a class from inside this class?

like this:

```
class someClass{

    int someInt;
    int anotherInt;
    String someString;
    Object someObject;

    Object getAllObjectsFromThisClass(){ // i want this
        return new Object[someInt, anotherIng, someString, someObject];
    }
}
```

or do i have to work with reflections?

My specified problem is -> i got masses of gui-classes with multible fields and i need to find objects with specific properties. (all gui-classes inherit from a view-class, which recieves the properties i have to search for inside the gui-classes.)

Comment: Yes, you'd have to work with reflection... this is precisely the kind of thing that reflection is designed for.

Comment: You can get the fields of the class using `Field[] fields = this.getClass().getDeclaredFields();` and access the fields via `Field[i].get(this)`.